# How to delete a object that attached another object in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, destructor, delete-operator

I'm working on this unit testing. I feel like to delete the both drill and battery, but it seems doesn't work (battery cannot be deleted maybe). Can I do anything on the destructor so as to deal with this issue?

```
 void test_rover::testDisconnectBattery() {
        Drill* drill = new Drill();
        drill->connectBattery(new Battery(10));
        drill->disconnectBattery();

        //CPPUNIT_ASSERT(drill->Connected()==false);
        delete drill;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(Object::getCount()==0);
    }
```

Device.cpp (Device is the base of drill)

```
    Device::Device() {
    }

    Device::Device(const Device& copy) {
    }

    Device::~Device() {
       delete _battery;
    }

    void Device::connectBattery(Battery *b){ 
        _battery = b;
    }

    void Device::disconnectBattery(){
        _battery = NULL;
    }
```

Battery.cpp

```
Battery::Battery(int power) {
    _power = power;
}

Battery::Battery(const Battery& copy) {
}

Battery::~Battery() {
}

int Battery::Power(){
    return _power;
}
```

Comment: When the destructor(`~Device`) is called, `_battery` is `NULL`, you need to `delete` the battery when you disconnect it or externally

Comment: you are using C++, why don't you use std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr as it fits?

Comment: I just added a 'delete _battery;' in disconnectBattery(), but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Also - why are you using ANY pointers in the first place? Why not just have Battery as a member of Drill? And, you never initialize `_battery` in Drill's constructor...

Comment: What if I call `connectBattery` with a batter allocated on stack?

Answer (score 0):

`disconnectBattery` is called first, which nulls out the pointer to the battery. Then when you `delete drill`, the destructor is called but the pointer is null so the `delete` command does nothing.

The issue you are dealing with is one of ownership. What piece of code "owns" the battery? If it's the drill then the drill should delete the battery when it's done with it (during disconnect, before nulling the pointer). If some other piece of code owns the battery then the drill should not ever delete the battery. You need to make a decision about this so that you can consistently implement the ownership.